# Angular proxy config with basic authorization

Tags: angular, typescript, proxy

I have a proxy for my API that requires basic authorization (username:password). This is what I have tried so far in my proxy config, but what am I missing?

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://example.com",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "headers": {"Authorization": "Basic ..."}
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding this:

```
"auth": "username:password",
```

If i remove the basic auth on my backend, it works like it should, but i would like to have authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I took the answer from here https://vividcode.io/use-proxy-in-angular-cli/

In nutshell

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://example.com",
        "secure": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "auth": "username:password"
    }
}
```